# Is it possible to extend a Mongoose Schema that has a discriminator

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Trying to extend an existing Schema that has a Discriminator, is this possible, I'd like to drop the discriminator and store in a separate Schema.

Schema A has a discriminator 'Table'
Schema B needs to have all fields from Schema A with different discriminator and stored in a separate collection?